# Delete duplicate records and update the mapping table

Tags: postgresql, update, delete

I have store_table_map and item_price_map. I want to delete duplicate records in store_table_map  and retain the latest row based on updated_date because i want to put constraints in store_id and item_id. But I also want first to update the item_price_map as seen below before deleting old duplicate records.

Current Table

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Here's the script

```
CREATE TABLE store_table_map (
    map_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    store_id int8 NOT NULL,
    item_id int8 NOT NULL,
    updated_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

INSERT INTO store_table_map (store_id,item_id,updated_date) VALUES 
(1,123,'2020-07-09')
,(1,123,'2020-07-10')
,(2,456,'2020-07-08')
,(2,456,'2020-07-10')
;

CREATE TABLE item_price_table_map (
    map_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    store_table_map_id int8 NOT NULL,
    price float8 NOT NULL,
    updated_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

INSERT INTO item_price_table_map (store_table_map_id,price,updated_date) VALUES 
(1,99.0,'2020-07-09')
,(2,199.0,'2020-07-10')
,(3,299.0,'2020-07-08')
,(4,399.0,'2020-07-10')
;
```

postgres version: PostgreSQL 9.2.24

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I would remove `map_id` as the primary key from `store_table_map` entirely and make `store_id, item_id` the primary key in there after you have removed the duplicates. I typically don't see any advantages of having a generated key in a mapping table like that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this is the old set-up and I cant change it, but how can I update the item_price_table_map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to create the mapping from the old map_id to the new one, this can be done using `distinct on()` and a self join:

```
select m1.map_id old_map_id, m2.new_map_id
from store_table_map m1
  join (
    select distinct on (store_id, item_id) store_id, item_id, map_id as new_map_id
    from store_table_map 
    order by store_id, item_id, updated_date desc
  ) m2 on (m1.store_id, m1.item_id) = (m2.store_id, m2.item_id)
```

The above returns:

```
old_map_id | new_map_id
-----------+-----------
         1 |          2
         2 |          2
         3 |          4
         4 |          4
```

This can be used in an UPDATE statement:

```
update item_price_table_map ip
  set store_table_map_id = t.new_map_id
from (  
  select m1.map_id old_map_id, m2.new_map_id
  from store_table_map m1
    join (
      select distinct on (store_id, item_id) store_id, item_id, map_id as new_map_id
      from store_table_map 
      order by store_id, item_id, updated_date desc
    ) m2 on (m1.store_id, m1.item_id) = (m2.store_id, m2.item_id)
) t 
where t.old_map_id = ip.store_table_map_id
  and ip.store_table_map_id <> t.new_map_id;
```

After that you can remove the rows with the now unused map_ids

```
delete from store_table_map stm
where not exists (select *
                  from item_price_table_map ip
                  where ip.store_table_map_id = stm.map_id);
```

(I could only test this on Postgres 12, but I think it should work on 9.2 too)

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name This works really well, thank you!!!

Comment: @EmmanuelLibradilla If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: i dont know how to accept it and marked it as resolve. I try to upvote but this pop-ups "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: There should be a "check mark" next to the voting buttons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: Oh, I didint see it, thanks! sorry for inconvenience :D